# is there any way to debug a chrome extension without setting a browser_action and a page_action?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning to write chrome extensions. Sometimes ,i do want to learn from the examples given on the chrome developer site. As the instruction says, i need a `browser_action` or a `page_action`, then right click ,then inspect popup. I am wondering whether there is other ways to debug the chrome extension.

And the other thing is , i have to write "`window.reload(true)`" in the debug console to reload the popup page, is there a better or more convenient way to do it?

Comment: Why do you consider writing `window.reload(true)` inconvenient?

Comment: Actually you can press F5 in the popup console and it will reload popup.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's not needed. Your extension either has a popup of some sorts, a background script of some sorts, or a content script of some sorts.

You already know how to debug a popup.

To debug a background page, you can go to `chrome://extensions/` with Developer mode enabled. Then you'll see a "background page" link next to extensions that have them - you can click that link to bring up Dev Tools for the extension.

To debug a content script, you should look into the page's own Dev Tools. The console output will be displayed alongside normal console. To type code in the console to execute in the [extension's context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), you need to change the the context from `<top frame>` to the extension in the UI:

[image: Extension context]

Comment: Instead of chrome://extensions, you can also use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc

Comment: ..or chrome://inspect/#extensions if we're trying to diversify.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to debug.
Chrome extensions also have background page and content-scripts.

Background page console you can find here: open chrome://extensions/ and under extension you'll see "Inspect views".

Content-scripts print messages to the page console.

Popup and other pages you can open in normal tab and inspect in its console. They are accessible by the url: "chrome-extension://**YOUR_EXTENSION_ID**/path/to/popup.html"